# Whosever or whose phone is ringing will be forfeited by the homeroom teacher?

Tags: grammar

{Whosever phone is ringing} will have it confiscated by the homeroom tracher.

I cannot use whoever's because I just need to use the word whosever, this archaic one for some reasons.   Does the subject of the noun clause in the bracket refer to the person or the phone after all?    Since the main verb is will have + Object + p.p, it is likely to mean the person.   Then, I found it difficult to  regard it as the subject because I thought it was the phone, it sounds like the phone ...etc

Could you help me clarify it?  Thank you always.

Comment: Your question is now quite different from the one I answered below. In order to get a good answer I suggest you firstly change the title. Replace the word _forfeited_ by _confiscated_ and remove _whose phone_. Then make it clear if you are asking about _whosever phone will be confiscated_ or _whosever phone will have it confiscated_. Also, it would be good to explain why you must use _whosever_ rather than _whoever's_.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. *Whosever phone* is the correct way to convey the intended meaning. But I think most people nowadays would say:

> Whoever's phone is ringing will be confiscated by the homeroom teacher.

*Garner's Modern American Usage* (p864) states:

> *Whosever* is the traditionally correct form, but it's very much on the wane. *Whoever's* is now the preferred colloquial form."

Some authentic examples:

> - Whoever's phone is ringing, you have about one minute until electronic devices are off.
> - Whoever's phone is ringing or vibrating: please turn it to silent.
> - Can whoever's phone we used on Friday to take a pic of our run please post it on here.

Comment: "Whosever" has waned so far that I do not recall ever having heard, read, or used it in a natural context.  (I speak American English.)  Would an n-graph show that "whosever" has become extinct?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/602701).  And it's [far from extinct](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22whosever%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AJOqlzUrgXPGayK7Q8SmdQgsuDQ5uZsKVw%3A1675562877127&ei=fQ_fY8SzB_Hz9APh17noAQ&ved=0ahUKEwiE5tuQpv38AhXxOX0KHeFrDh0Q4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22whosever%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAM6BQghEKsCOgUIABCABFCDDViTFGDrFGgAcAB4AIAB9gGIAdgIkgEFMS43LjGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books) this side of the Atlantic.